# Upon restarting a Jupyter notebook, automatically run 1st/nth cell only (to load modules and other variables), ideally using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In addition to loading required modules, in the first cell of the jupyter notebook, I usually load variables (e.g. metadata, tables etc.). So every time when I restart a jupyter notebook, I need to run the 1st cell of the notebook. I know this is not a big issue, but sometimes can be an annoyance. For example, if I would be working at the end of the notebook and need to restart it, I would have to scroll all the way up, run the first cell, and then scroll all the way back to resume the work.

I hope there is a way to automatically run 1st (or any n'th) cell of a jupyter notebook when it is restarted. I wonder if anybody knows if such a functionality exists.

Comment: JupyterLab has "Restart Kernel and Run up to Selected Cell" command since version 2.0. It is very useful, I have it mapped to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Ok, I am using version 3.0.14 and I don't really have that option, which is strange. I just have a single restart-related option: "Restart Kernel and Run All Cells". Do you have any suggestions regarding how to get/enable the option you mentioned i.e. "Restart Kernel and Run up to Selected Cell" ?

Comment: I simply want to run the first cell upon restart. "Run up to Selected Cell" would be great if I'd want to rerun the "upstream" code, which is not always the case for me. I put a bounty on this question to draw more attention. I hope there is somebody out there with a solution in mind.

Comment: It should be in the `Kernel` menu - it is definitely there in JupyterLab 3.2.4. If you want to add it as a shortcut the command ID is `notebook:restart-and-run-to-selected`. I don't know why it would not be there.

Comment: Oh yes, I was looking into the `Run` menu, sorry. It is definitely there in the `Kernel` menu.

Comment: Upon every restart, I would not want to rerun all of the "upstream" code so "Run up to Selected" option does not really help. I wish there was a way to run only the 1st cell, upon restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install jupyter notebook extensions (see here how it is done: https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html ).
2. Use the *Initialization cells* extension (https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/init_cell/README.html ).

It allows you to mark one or more cells as 'Initialisation cells' that will run when the notebook is opened or on clicking the (then added) 'initialization button' in the main toolbar.

The cell toolbar selector can be found under `View` > `Cell Toolbar` > `Initialization Cell`.

Not 100% what you are looking for as you need to click an extra button after restarting the notebook. On the other hand, scrolling up and down is avoided and it is an easy fix.

Comment: I like the concept of `Initialization Cell`. Somehow, I never come across it. I guess it would be useful for many users like me. Almost all of the jupyter notebook I have seen have some sort of an "initialization cell", often located at the top of the notebook as a 1st cell.

Comment: I wonder if this extension (`init_cell`) only works in jupyter-notebook and not in jupyter-lab, because the documentation only shows jupyter-notebook and I could not get it working so far in jupyter-lab.

Comment: Did you test this extension in jupyter-lab?

Comment: No, sorry, haven’t used jupyterlab in a while…